# Slowing down connections to online games?

Tags: networking, router

Would it be possible to slow down connections to online games to a point where the user experience is so unpleasant that the game is unplayable? I was thinking of doing something such as changing my router's QoS settings so that it significantly increases latency for packets that are for port 1000 and above.

Does such a setting exist?

Comment: why not just first assign an internal IP address for each computer that you want to do this for by their MAC address in the DHCP reservation table, then using those same QoS settings, assign a sliver of your bandwidth to each of those computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of terrible person are you? Joking aside, there are two possible things.

One would be for you to use a ton of bandwidth; you could simply download a large torrent to accomplish this. Another more permanent solution would be to change QoS settings, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Also, if you are simply trying to get someone not to play a game, at school for example, you could use other non-network restrictions that would also prevent single player games.

Answer (score 0):

Many routers have QoS settings that can be applied on a per host basis.  I.e, you could rate limit everyone (by default) and disable rate limiting for, say, your own machine.

Answer (score 0):

You would use QoS on the router not to adjust **latency** on the packets, but rather adjust the **bandwidth** allocation for the port the game runs on. Or adjust bandwidth to a particular client, whichever your router is capable of or is practical for whatever your trying to accomplish (hehe).

**Option 1 - Adjust Bandwidth for Port/Protocol**

If your application sends data based on port 1000 and 1001, in QoS you would assign a low bandwidth setting for those ports. Sometimes routers require you create a "Service Name" for a particular port or set of ports, then set bandwidth for that Service Name (essentially a port group).

Most consumer routers will allow you to set a priority level and some allow you to actually modify the bandwidth manually (in Kb/s for Upload and Download).

**Option 2 - Adjust Bandwidth for Client**

Some routers actually allow you to set bandwidth allocation to a particular subnet, IP or group of IPs. I've only seen this on routers designed for corporate networks.

This option wouldn't suit your needs anyway, as this would slow the connection for allow inbound and outbound traffic for the client. If you're only looking to limit the bandwidth for one particular application, then Option 1 would be better.